# insert manually data into a smartgwt ListGrid

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

I started developing with smartgwt few weeks ago and I am having a problem.
I have a ListGrid and i don't use any datasource for the displayed data. I do all the insertions manually with a ListGridRecord[]. It works fine but i don't know how to insert 
a cell in specific row, column. Any idea??
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ListGrid.getRecord(index).setAttribute(property, value);